# How to find the following integration

Tags: probability, statistics, measure-theory, statistical-inference

Let $X_1, \cdots, X_n$ be $iid$ normal random variables with unknown mean $\mu$ and known variance $\sigma^2$. How to find $E[\Phi(\bar X)]$, where $\bar X:=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i}{n}$, please? I guess the answer should be $\Phi(\mu)$. Here is how I started. Note that $Y:= \bar X$ is also normal with mean $\mu$ and variance $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$.

$$E[\Phi(\bar X)] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \Phi(y) f_Y(y) dy.$$

Let $z=\frac{y-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}$ and the above integration becomes

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \Phi(\mu+\frac{\sigma z}{\sqrt{n}}) \phi(z) dz$$

I could not proceed any further from here. Does anyone know what to do, please? Thank you!

Comment: Is $\Phi$ the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal distribution?

Comment: Yes, it is the cdf of standard normal random variable.

Comment: Here is a hint:  if $\Phi(y)$ is the cumulative distribution function representing $\Pr[Y \le y]$, then $\Phi'(y) = f_Y(y)$, the density of $Y$ evaluated at $Y = y$.

Comment: @heropup I tried that already using integration by parts. It didn't seem work. Is that what you suggest?

Comment: $$\int g(x)g'(x) \, dx = \int u \, du = \frac{u^2}{2} + C = \frac{g(x)^2}{2} + C.$$

Comment: @heropup Just let you know that $\Phi(\cdot)$ and $F_Y(y)$ are not the same question.

Comment: Indeed, you are right; however, an appropriate substitution will transform the general normal distribution to a standard normal distribution.

Comment: @heropup I updated my attempt. However, I still could not get a useful answer. Could you tell me how to proceed, please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14920/discussion-between-20824-and-heropup).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know how you got to the displayed integral in your question, but
here is how to evaluate it once you get there. The result does not match
what you claim is the answer.

Let $Y = \Phi(X)$ where $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. Then,
$$\begin{align}
E[Y] = E[\Phi(X)] &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \Phi(x)f_X(x)\,\mathrm dx \tag{1}
\end{align}$$
But, if $Z\sim N(0,1)$ is independent of $X$, then 
$$P\{Z \leq x\mid X = x\} = P\{Z \leq x\} = \Phi(x)$$
and so we can recognize the integral in $(1)$ as
$$\begin{align}
E[\Phi(X)] &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \Phi(x)f_X(x)\,\mathrm dx\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty P\{Z \leq x\mid X = x\}f_X(x)\,\mathrm dx\\
&= P\{Z \leq X\}&{\scriptstyle{\text{by the continuous version of the
law of total probability}}}\\
&= P\{Z-X \leq 0\}\\
&= \Phi\left(\frac{0-(-\mu)}{\sqrt{1 + \sigma^2}}\right) &{\scriptstyle{\text{this follows because}~ Z-X \sim N(-\mu,1+\sigma^2)}}\\
&= \Phi\left(\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{1 + \sigma^2}}\right)
\end{align}$$

Comment: FYI, this question occurred when I tried to find the UMVUE for $\Phi(\mu)$. It is clear that $\Phi(\bar X)$ is a natural candidate since it is a function of complete and sufficient statistic and all left to show is that it is also unbiased. Hence, I need to find the expectation. I guess now I need to do some manipulation on this guess.

Comment: How do I write $\Phi(ax)$ as something like $a'\Phi(x)$, please?

Answer (score 5):

Find $E[\Phi(c\bar X)]$ where $X_i \sim N(\mu, 1)$ and $c$ is a constant. Then, proceed following Dilip but replace $X$ with $\bar Xc.$
Let $Z\sim N(0,1)$ be independent of all $X_i.$ Then
$$\begin{align}
E[\Phi(c\bar X)]
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty P\{Z \leq cy\mid \bar X = y\}f_\bar X(y)\,\mathrm dy\\
&= P\{Z \leq c\bar X\}\\
&= P\{Z-c\bar X \leq 0\} \\
&= \Phi\left(\frac{c\mu}{\sqrt{1 + c^2/n}}\right)
\end{align}$$
If we then choose $c$ to make this last expression equal to $\Phi(\mu),$ then we will obtain its MVUE. In this case $c=\sqrt\frac n{n-1}.$ If  $\sigma^2\ne1$, then $c=\sqrt\frac n{n-\sigma^2}$ for $n$ sufficiently large.