# Expected value of Normal CDF at normal value

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

I am working on the problem below:

[image]

The solution contains the following line that I don't understand:

[image]

Why is the expectation given X?

Comment: $Z$ is assumed independent of $X$. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/820211/321264.

Comment: Would you mind explaining in a bit more detail please? I'm confused because the naive definition is $P(A)=E(I_A)$ for an event A.

Comment: If $Z$ is independent of $X$, you have $P(Z\le X)=P(Z\le X\mid X)=E[I(Z\le X)\mid X]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like when two events $A$ and $B$ are independent, we have $P(A\mid B)=P(A)$, when two random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent, it is true that $E[\,Y\mid X\,]=E[Y]$. The author applies this trick with $Y=\Bbb I(Z\le X)$. This explains why they are allowed to write what they wrote; in order to understand why what they wrote is useful to the rest of the proof, we would need to see the rest of the proof.